# Chrome limitations with SharePoint

Tags: limitations, chrome

I have a list of links on a SharePoint 2010 site.  The links that go to a network browser do not work when Chrome is the browser.  I've seen a few articles that say some actions can't be done from Chrome, specifically open Excel.  Are links to folders also unable to be opened using Chrome?

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "network browser"?

Comment: Perhaps network browser = file shares?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the issues with SP 2010 when using Netscape and Chrome are due to the lack of support for ActiveX controls. Look to if there are any add-ins for Chrome for ActiveX support.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls are a security risk.

See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724751/open-local-filesfile-using-chrome

But there is a chrome extension that will approximate what you are trying to do:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld?hl=en